# Swift - Select Random Function

Tags: swift

I think this could be useful.

I've got a bunch of functions, in an array. 
For example, let's say its:

```
var randomFunction = [addEnemyFromCornersTogether(), addEnemyFromCornersWait()]
var randomFunctionDelay = NSTimeInterval(5.0)
```

I want to choose them randomly with delay set in a variable.
No idea how to do that. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func fireEvent() {
    var randomFunction = [addEnemyFromCornersTogether(), addEnemyFromCornersWait()]
    let choice = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomFunction.count)))
    var choiceFunction: () = randomFunction[choice]
    let delay = 5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        choiceFunction
        fireEvent()
    })
}
```

Comment: It works, but the delay seems not to be working. And when I wrap it up in a function, and repeatItForever the app just freezes when it's supossed to execute. Any idea why?

Comment: choiceFunction in brackets at the bottom shows error: Expression resolves to an unused I-value. :(
EDIT: It works, it's awesome, thank you so much! It was just my interference with the code. Thank you Kris!